# Most preferred Form submission method using PHP

Tags: html, forms

I am a PHP developer. I have been developing websites. I have seen a lot of forms without action. I know that means self. Just for the sake of knowledge, I want to know the best suggested and secure way to submit a form especially using POST method.

Comment: What you are probably seeing is the form being translated into an AJAX request, which can make sense for user interfaces when you don't want to reload the whole page. It depends on what you need

Comment: @Pekka웃 submission without page refresh or submission on the same page is not my question. My question is the most preferred way to submit a form using POST method even using AJAX or PHP

Comment: There is only one method really. Can you clarify what you are asking about, maybe make two examples?

Comment: Actually my question is, leaving the Action attribute blank or using a page name. What is secure actually?

Comment: The value of the attribute doesn't make any difference security wise. If you are a beginner, perhaps the entire process becomes clearer to you as you learn more. (It's certainly a good habit to always think about security and good design though!)

Comment: absolutely correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clear from your question that you do not have a good grasp on what forms are and how they work. All forms are used in the same manner and are merely a convenient container used to submit data.  I highly recommend reading the following link.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML%2FForms%2FSending_and_retrieving_form_data

There is no such thing as an insecure form submission. You can however make submissions across an unsecured channel. Using https for all your connections is the standard response.

As an additional note, you CANNOT use ajax to submit a form. What you can do is write explicit javascript that reads the data and independently submits it.  All submissions using a form submit are synchronous and require a page load as they create a full HTTP request of either GET or POST.

Comment: I am actually a beginner and been playing around with this stuff but i like to get deeper. Thanks for your concern. Its nicely explained.